# Understanding what the query is and does?

Tags: sql, t-sql

This is going to be a strange request, can someone explain in plain English what the query below is doing especially the <>0 bit.

```
Select S.[Silks_Skey], MC.[MajorColour_Skey], MC.[MajorColour]
from [dbo].[Silks] S 
inner join [dbo].[SubColour] SC on CHARINDEX(SC.[SubColour],S.[SilksName]) <> 0
inner join [dbo].[MajorColour] MC on SC.[MajorColour] = MC.[MajorColour]
```

Thanks

W

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`charindex(expressionToFind, expressionToSearch)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186323.aspx) function searches for the occurance of a string in another string.  If the string is not found, it returns `0`, otherwise it returns the position of the first string in the second.

```
inner join [dbo].[SubColour] SC on CHARINDEX(SC.[SubColour],S.[SilksName]) <> 0
```

So the join looks for all SubColours that are contained in the silk's name.  For example, if the silk was called "high-quality blue and green silk", this would join in the `blue` and `green` subcolours.

Comment: Can you help with then, This is my whole query but I have been told to remove the union and chan it to where Red = Red this is Major to Silks name.

Select S.[Silks_Skey], MC.[MajorColour_Skey] 
from [dbo].[Silks] S 
inner join [dbo].[SubColour] SC on CHARINDEX(SC.[SubColour],S.[SilksName]) <> 0
inner join [dbo].[MajorColour] MC on SC.[MajorColour] = MC.[MajorColour]
       
UNION ALL
 
Select S.[Silks_Skey], MC.[MajorColour_Skey] 
from [dbo].[Silks] S 
inner join [dbo].[MajorColour] MC on CHARINDEX(MC.[MajorColour],S.[SilksName]) <> 0
 
ORDER BY S.[Silks_Skey]

Answer (score 1):

The silk name contains the sub colour name related to it. Sub colours are related to Major colours.  Return silks and their related major colours if the silk name contains the sub colour name.